# I want to know about React(16.13.1) which I have created by create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, project-structure

There is a catalog about my new program, but I can't understand what these documents represent
[image]

Comment: Service worker is for adding Progressive Web App(PWA) support and test file is for automated testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find more information about the structure that create-react-app generates in its docs:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

*If you search by file name...*

serviceWorker: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/

setupTests: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#initializing-test-environment